# javascript - remove element/node with no ID and specific content

Tags: javascript, element

I'm struggling to decipher a way to remove several specific href elements which contain no IDs and are children of individual parents with no IDs.

The best I can manage is identifying the four offending, out of 8 or 9 href tags (and the number may vary), by a specific word within the URL itself.  For this, I do the following:

```
<script language=javascript>
var xx = document.getElementById('theID').getElementsByTagName('a');
var ptn=/\=media/;
for(var i=0; i<xx.length; i++) {
    if(ptn.exec(xx[i])){
    alert(xx[i]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Of course all this gives me is the four specific URLs within the href where "=media" is present.  Now, somehow, I need to be able to remove either these href elements, or their parent elements (which happen to be unordered list tags).  It's not until I get a level higher (table cell) that I gain access to an element ID, or anything distinguishing besides a particular word within the URL itself.

I'm open to any approach at this point - PHP may be an option (I really haven't explored this yet), but for this, javascript was my first logical choice. I can't tamper with the page that generates the links directly, only a secondary page which gets included at page load time.

Any pointers on how to solve this??

======================== final solution =====================

```
<script language=javascript>
var xx = document.getElementById('theID').getElementsByTagName('a');
var ptn=/\=media/;
for(var i=0; i<xx.length; i++) {
    while(ptn.exec(xx[i].href)){
        alert(xx[i]);
        xx[i].parentNode.removeChild(xx[i]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the ID to remove an element.  You only need a reference to the element (which you seem to have).

instead of this:

```
alert(xx[i]);
```

try this:

```
XX[i].parentElement.removeChild(xx[i]);
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I was close a time or two, but couldn't get to the finish line.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  Don't forget to use Andy E's suggestion of using the href property in your regex test.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [*removeChild()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild) on the parent element, like so:

```
xx[i].parentNode.removeChild(xx[i]);
```

As a side note, your regular expression isn't being executed on the *href* property.  Change your if statement to:

```
if(ptn.exec(xx[i].href)){
```

Comment: Good point - I've updated accordingly.  Also, seems executing in an "if" is problematic - I've switched to "while" and get the results I was anticipating.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parent = xx[i].parentNode;
parent.removeChild(xx[i]);
```

http://www.onlinetools.org/articles/unobtrusivejavascript/chapter2.html has some nice examples of similar operations (scroll down).

Comment: *removeNode()* is a proprietary method and isn't implemented in all browsers.  Stick with *removeChild()*.

Comment: @Andy - yes, just looked that up and confirmed.  Edited my answer.